# Reader monad, how bind readers works?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm a beginner in Haskell. I learned How to create a Reader and How to query a shared variables. I looked into the source code of Reader.hs in Hugs98

```
instance Monad (Reader r) where
return a = Reader $ \_ -> a

m >>= k  = Reader $ \r -> 
                  runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

Here I can see (return a) creates a Reader wrapping a function that takes a value and return a

m >>= k is what I can't understand. first how is that can be applied ? maybe example of two readers binded can help ?

secondly the implementation is some how vague for me
I don't understand the point of applying k to the result of (runReader m r) ?

Thanks

Comment: Since Reader and runReader are just there to go between two isomorphic types, just pretend they are not there, and then it becomes more understandable.

Comment: I still have a problem to understand this specific behavior when monad are functions. There seems to be a missing explanation in all of the monad tutoring - monad are not all the same for example when k is apply in >>= for the Maybe monad that the end of the binding k is fed and give m b that's all but for a Reader the same k which gives m b needs now to be unwrapped and wrapped up - but from the type signature it follows that k when fed with an a produces a Reader r b - this is the Reader we look for and should end the binding as in the Maybe monad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>=` aka bind has the signature: `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. If we try to make this signature specific to Reader i.e replacing `m` with `Reader r` we will find that it becomes:

`(Reader r) a -> (a -> (Reader r) b) -> (Reader r) b`

Which is same as:

`Reader r a -> (a -> Reader r b) -> Reader r b`

Now we need to write such a function:

`(>>=) m k = ...` where `m` is `Reader r a` and `k` is `(a -> Reader r b)` and we need to return `Reader r b`

How can you create `Reader r b` as this is something that we have to return ? Well, `k` is a function that will allow you to create `Reader r b` but `k` need some value of type `a` to return `Reader r b`.

How we can get a value of type `a` (so that we can use function `k`) ? Looks like `m` parameter which is of type `Reader r a` can help us to get a value of type `a`.

How do we get value of `a` from `Reader r a`? `runReader` has a type `Reader r a -> r -> a`, so if we call `runReader` on `m` we will get `(r -> a)` but we were looking for value of `a` type and what we got is `(r -> a)` and it seems we don't have any `r` value to get `a`. It seems we are stuck as we don't have any other parameter to look for.

Let's assume we somehow has some `r` value (called `r_val`) so that we can do:

`let a_val = runReader m r_val` gives us value of type `a`.

from `a` we need to get `Reader r b` using k

`let reader_r_b_val = k a_val` gives us value of type `Reader r b` and that's it, we got what we need to return, lets combine all the above 2 lets:

`k (runReader m r_val)` which is `Reader r b` BUT we are not done yet, we need to do something of `r_val` which was just a placeholder. Lets say we take `r_val` as param

`\r_val -> k (runReader m r_val)` which is of type `r -> Reader r b` ... Hmmm but we only need to return `Reader r b` .. can we somehow wrap `r -> Reader r b` into a `Reader r b` ?

`Reader $ (\r_val -> k (runReader m r_val))` has a type `Reader r (Reader r b)` .. looks like we are almost there we just need to convert `Reader r (Reader r b)` to `Reader r b` i.e we need the to convert inner `Reader r b` to just `b` and for that we can use `runReader` so:

`Reader $ (\r_val -> runReader (k (runReader m r_val)) r_val)`

Answer (score 3):

Reader is defined as:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

So it's really just a function of type `r -> a` with some extra encapsulation. This makes sense, as the Reader really just provides an extra input to all the actions in the monad.

If we strip the encapsulation and only use the `r -> a` function, the types of the monadic functions are:

```
return :: a -> (r -> a) -- or: a -> r -> a
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> (r -> b)) -> (r -> b) -- or: (r -> a) -> (a -> r -> b) -> r -> b
```

Looking at this it is a lot easier to see what is required of us. If you look at the type `a -> (r -> a)` and see that this is equivalent to `a -> r -> a`, you can see that you can look at this function in two ways. One is that you take an argument of `a` and return a function of type `r -> a`, the other is to look at is as a function that takes an `a` and an `r` and returns an `a`. You can implement return using either of these views:

```
return a = \r -> a -- or: return a r = a
```

The bind is trickier, but the same logic applies. In the first type signature I gave, it is not immediately evident that the third `r` in the type is actually also an input, while the second type signature makes this very easy to see. So let's start with implementing the second type signature:

```
(>>=) rToA aAndRToB r = ...
```

So we have a value of type `r`, a function of type `r -> a` and a function of type `a -> r -> b` and our goal is to make a value of type `b` out of that. The only `b` in our input is in the `a -> r -> b` function so we will need to use that, but we do not have an `a` to feed it, so we need to get one. The `r -> a` function can provide one, if we have an `r` for it. We do have an `r`, it's our third input. So we can simply apply the functions until we get our `b`:

```
(>>=) rToA aAndRToB r = b where
  a = rToA r
  b = aAndRToB a r
```

Here you can see that we provide the `r`-value to every action (which is the goal of the Reader monad) while also chaining the `a`-value from one action to the next (which is the goal of `(>>=)`). You can also write this in a way that mimics the first type signature like this:

```
(>>=) rToA aToRToB = \r -> (aToRToB (rToA r)) r
```

which if you rename the variables looks very similar to the definition of Reader's bind, but without using `Reader` and `runReader`:

```
m >>= k = /r -> k (m r) r
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so let's look at `m >>= k`. Here `m` is a reader, and `k` is a *function* that produces a reader. So what does this do?

```
runReader m r
```

OK, so this is running `m` with `r` as the input to be read.

```
k (runReader m r)
```

This takes the output from running `m` and passes it to `k`. This makes `k` return *another* reader.

```
runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```

This takes the reader returned by `k` and runs that (with the same input `r` for reading).

You follow all that?

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes the problem for me is here *k (runReader m r)*
I don't know how that can be used ? How can I bind multiple readers that one feeds the another ? can you provide a simple example of that ?
Thanks again

Comment: As shown, `k (runReader m r)` returns a reader. We then pass that to the outer-most `runReader` to run it (again, with the same input `r`).

Answer (score 1):

First, what the Reader is for.

Consider that you have a pure function f x y, and a pure function g y. Now you figure out that g needs to use f inside, but it only has one argument that it can supply f with! A typical solution is one of the following:

1. modify API so that g now has two arguments, both x and y (and the caller now has to compute it, even if g doesn't call f);
2. create a global variable that g will read to provide f with that argument (g is no longer pure);
3. create a global variable that f will read (f is no longer pure).

Familiar? The latter two solutions are probably the most common, but they are ugly. The first solution requires a uniform way for the caller to interact with g, that's the difficulty. By wrapping g in a Reader monad, we provide such interface: the caller h :: a -> b either knows how to compute x and provide it (runReader (g y) x), or the caller can wrap itself into a Reader too, and delegate the computation of x to its caller (turns into h :: a -> Reader x b).

In essence, solution 1, introducing the extra argument in function g, means its signature is g :: y -> x -> z, which is a function g :: y -> (x -> z). Reader monad permits to abstract away the (x -> z) part, so you have g :: y -> Reader x z. The abstraction permits to bind functions that need x or pass x along to others *in a uniform way*.

Without Reader monad:

```
h :: x -> z
h = \x -> g y x -- caller doesn't know how to compute x
  where y = .... -- some computation that h knows how to do

g y = \x -> f x y
```

(h could be written neater as h x = ..., but I deliberately express it as a lambda, so it will be easier to compare to below):

This is the same as:

```
h :: Reader x z
h = Reader $ \x -> g y x
  where y = ...

g :: y -> x -> z
g y = \x -> f x y
```

With Reader monad:

```
h :: Reader x z
h = g y
  where y = ...

g :: y -> Reader x z
g y = Reader $ \x -> f x y
```

Tidy up:

```
h :: Reader x z
h = g y
  where y = ...

g :: y -> Reader x z
g y = do
        x <- ask
        return $ f x y
```

Now to (>>=).

```
(Reader f) >>= g = Reader $ \x -> -- this is the x we are given, 
                                  -- so need to pass it to f and g y
                     case g (f x) of -- g y is Reader x z,
                                     -- so need to call the wrapped x -> z 
                         Reader g' -> g' x
```

The pattern matching above is the same as:

```
m >>= g = Reader $ \x -> runReader (g (runReader m x)) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's derive the specific type scheme for `Reader`'s `>>=`, then simplify it a little.

```
-- General monad
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

-- Reader monad
(>>=) :: Reader r a -> (a -> Reader r b) -> Reader r b

-- Let me put it in a (syntactically incorrect, but) more illustrative form
(>>=) :: (Reader r -> a) -> (a -> (Reader r -> b)) -> (Reader r -> b)

-- A reader is a function of type (r -> a), packed into a Reader context.
-- If we want to access the wrapped function, we can easily do it with runReader.

-- With this in mind, let's see how it would be without the extra context.
(>>=) :: (r -> a) -> (a -> (r -> b)) -> (r -> b)
```

We can think of `>>=` as a function that takes two parameters, `m` (a monadic value) and `f` (a function), and returns `result` (another monadic value).

Let's now write an implementation for this simplified type structure.

```
-- Takes m and f, returns result
m >>= f = result

-- The types
m      :: r -> a
f      :: a -> (r -> b)
result :: r -> b

-- Implementation
m >>= f = \x -> (f (m x)) x

-- A quick How-We-Got-Here
mResult = m x  -- :: a
fResult = f mResult  -- :: r -> b
result  = \x -> fResult x
        = \x -> (f mResult) x
        = \x -> (f (m x)) x
```

Time to bring `Reader` back in the game. The form `f >>= m = result` still stands, but the types change a bit, and with them the implementation will change a bit, too.

```
-- The types
m      :: Reader (r -> a)
f      :: a -> Reader (r -> b)
result :: Reader (r -> b)

-- Functions we easily used before, are now in a "Reader".
-- But we can easily unwrap and access them with "runReader".

-- Now "result" is not just a function, but one in a "Reader".
-- But we can easily wrap it with "Reader".

-- Apply these tools on our How-We-Got-Here analogy from before.
mResult = (runReader m) x  -- :: a
fResult = f mResult  -- :: Reader (r -> b)
result  = Reader $ \x -> (runReader fResult) x
        = Reader $ \x -> (runReader (f mResult)) x
        = Reader $ \x -> (runReader (f ((runReader m) x))) x
```

After all, the actual implementation.

```
m >>= f = Reader $ \x -> (runReader (f ((runReader m) x))) x

-- Remove the unnecessary parens
m >>= f = Reader $ \x -> runReader (f (runReader m x)) x

-- Different letters
m >>= k = Reader $ \r -> runReader (k (runReader m r)) r
```